# How do I get rid of this error warning with unity targeting the wrong .NET framework in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so whenever I try to use Visual Studio with the Unity game engine I get this strange error message.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8qQF.png
I have no idea how to fix this as I am very new to VS and Unity and am only following the tutorials, so any help would be appreciated.
I managed to go on the second option and downloaded .NET framework version 4.8 however it didn't really work

Comment: If you follow the instructions, it _should just work_.  That's a pretty explicit error message.  When you create a project, you associate it with with a particular version of the Framework.  If you try to work with it in Visual Studio and that version isn't installed on your machine, you will get that message.  Your choice is to change the project settings to match what you have installed on your machine or install another version of the framework.  Your description of _"it didn't really work"_ tells us nothing.  Don't expect any help with that.

Comment: Rather download and install the missing .NET framework 4.7.1 .. Unity doesn't yet support 4.8 afaik (depending on the Unity version probably)

Comment: @derHugo .NET 4.x versions are binary replacements. You can't install them side-by-side or downgrade. You can easily change a project's target version though. The error complains that the *targeting pack* is missing, something that can be installed by VS Installer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well yes .. what I mean is install that .NET framework 4.7.1 targeting pack via VS Installer ... What I ment by my comment is the one for `.NET framework 4.8` (which how I unserstand is what OP installed) won't help if it is targeting 4.7.1

Answer (score 2):

set the .NET Framework target version down to a version below 4.8. You can set it in Visual Studio in the Project tab --> Properties --> Application. Alternatively you can install the .NET Framework needed but I am not sure if Unity supports it. I would recommend to use just an older version.

Comment: This is just a temporary solution .. it will be overwritten as soon as Unity recompiles/rebuilds the project (I know because I had this before ;) )